# SetInterval Form Submit with AJAX Rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I want `.edit_canvas` to submit every 5 seconds via AJAX. Right now it seems like nothing is happening. I have no console errors though.

Javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
  // Get html content of canvas element
  var canvasContent = $('.canvas').html();
  // Populate hidden field with canvas content
  $('#canvas-content').val(canvasContent);

  // Submit form with AJAX
  $('.edit_canvas').submit(function() {
      var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();

      $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
          type: 'POST',
          data: valuesToSubmit,
          dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
      }).success(function(json){
          $('.canvas').css('background', 'pink');
      });

      // Prevent normal behaviour
      return false;
  });
}, 5000);
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @canvas do |f| %>      
    <%= f.hidden_field :content, value: "", id: "canvas-content" %>
    <%= f.submit "Save", id: "save-canvas" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is attaching a submit event handler, not submitting the form via ajax.
Just remove the submit code and it should work

```js
setInterval(function(){
  // Get html content of canvas element
  var canvasContent = $('.canvas').html();
  // Populate hidden field with canvas content
  $('#canvas-content').val(canvasContent);

  // Submit form with AJAX
      var valuesToSubmit = $('.edit_canvas').serialize();

      $.ajax({
          url: $('.edit_canvas').attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
          type: 'POST',
          data: valuesToSubmit,
          dataType: "JSON" // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls, and json is standard
      }).success(function(json){
          $('.canvas').css('background', 'pink');
      });

}, 5000);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks man. This seems like a primitive approach to auto save? Is it advisable to submit every few seconds?

Comment: @Moppy it depends on the application, if the data is changing at this rate and you need keep track of it, I don't see a problem. Though you might want to look into other technologies like websockets.